# How to login with HTTP basic authentication to ACCESS the website- Test Cafe with Gherkin and cucumber

Tags: testing, cucumber, basic-authentication, testcafe, gherkin

*All links, project name and company name has been modified and are not original.*

We have a basic HTTP authentication popup that appears when we are accessing out test/staging environments.

I am wondering, how can I enter the login information into the popup login window or send an api request in advance to save the cookie?

Because otherwise, I can't run the automation on our test environment. When the test access the page, I see a white website showing "**unauthorized**" in small letters.

This is what the login prompt looks like when accessing the Test/Staging env

[image: What staging website looks like]

We are using following plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gherkin-testcafe

What I am asking is very similar to this question: [Testing http basic authentication with Cucumber and RSpec in Rails 3.2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10735923/testing-http-basic-authentication-with-cucumber-and-rspec-in-rails-3-2-3)

I have tried adding a role and using TestCafe http-authentication.html

Here is what I have tested so far:

TestCafe trying to use role:

```
const { Role } = require('testcafe');
const regularAccUser = Role('https://website/login', async t => {
  await t
    .typeText('#login', 'username')
    .typeText('#password', 'password')
    .click('#sign-in');
});

Given("I am open Dealer's login page", async t => {
  await t
    .useRole(regularAccUser)
    .navigateTo(`${url}/login`);
});
```

That gives me:

```
ERROR CompositeParserException: Parser errors:
(7:3): expected: #EOF, #Comment, #BackgroundLine, #TagLine, #ScenarioLine, #ScenarioOutlineLine, #Empty, got 'Correct action happens when user provide either wrong or correct login information'
    at Function.Errors.CompositeParserException.create (/Users/dennis/Projects/src/company/project/node_modules/gherkin/lib/gherkin/errors.js:27:13)
    at Parser.parse (/Users/dennis/Projects/src/company/project/node_modules/gherkin/lib/gherkin/parser.js:72:45)
    at specFiles.forEach.specFile (/Users/dennis/Projects/src/company/project/node_modules/gherkin-testcafe/src/compiler.js:43:33)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at GherkinTestcafeCompiler.getTests (/Users/dennis/Projects/src/company/project/node_modules/gherkin-testcafe/src/compiler.js:42:20)
    at getTests (/Users/dennis/Projects/src/company/project/node_modules/testcafe/src/runner/bootstrapper.js:79:47)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (/Users/dennis/Projects/src/company/project/node_modules/babel-runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:17:30)
    at /Users/dennis/Projects/src/company/project/node_modules/babel-runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:28:13
```

If I try using:

```
import {Role} from 'testcafe'
```

I get:

```
tests/ui/stepDefinitions/login/login.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import { Role } from 'testcafe';
                                                                     ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

Using TestCafe's HTTP Authentication:

```
Feature: Login with correct and wrong info functionallity
  .page('website/login')
  .httpAuth({
  username: 'username',
  password: 'password',
  })
  Correct action happens when user provide either wrong or correct login information

  @loginFunc
  Scenario: Should NOT be able to login without filling in any credentials
    Given I am open Dealer's login page
    When I am login in with "empty" and "empty"
    Then I should NOT be able to press the login button
```

I am getting following:

````
Feature: Login with correct and wrong info functionallity
 ✖ Scenario: Should NOT be able to login without filling in any credentials

   1) Cannot obtain information about the node because the specified selector does not match any node in the DOM tree.

         | Selector('button[data-qa="qa-login-submit-button"]')
       > |   Selector('button[data-qa="qa-login-submit-button"]')

      Browser: Chrome 72.0.3626 / Mac OS X 10.14.3

         32 |  }
         33 |});
         34 |
         35 |Then("I should NOT be able to press the login button", async t => {
         36 |  await t
       > 37 |    .expect(submitButton.hasAttribute('disabled')).ok()
         38 |    .expect(h1.exists).eql(true);
         39 |});
    ```

It is basically showing me a white screen and saying: "**unauthorized**" in small letters.
````

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. It will help you craft solid questions that will hopefully get useful answers. And please...no screeenshots.  Anyway...I'd start with the docs: https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/authentication/

Comment: Why no screenshot? It helps contribute and give a better understanding of what I am trying to accomplish. 
And if there are specific areas you want me to improve, please provide that and not just a link to where to read about asking questions :) thanks!

Comment: In the short-term, screenshots can help visually.  But others can't cut/paste the necessary code to easily repro the issue.  Otherwise, you've edited the question  with sufficient info + code now.  Here's an upvote...

Comment: Could you please rewrite your test without using the Gherkin syntax?

Comment: nope, where I work they wanna use Gherkin

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any post/get requests with the Basic HTTP. Instead, you can log in using the [Role mechanism](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/authentication/user-roles.html):

> When you switch to a role for the first time, TestCafe internally creates a branch of this role for this particular test run. All cookies set by your further actions will be appended to this branch. This branch will be used whenever you switch back to this role from the same test run.

Comment: I was not able to get it to work. I have updated the main question with logs, code and more information.

Comment: It looks like you run tests in the wrong way.  Could you please describe how (programmatically or CLI) you are running your tests?